# Imac stuck on boot screen

Tags: startup, high-sierra, screen

I know that this is a recurring topic but wondered if any one of you is experiencing this issue with mac os high sierra?

I don’t know what really happened on the eve; but the day after when i switched it on i got stuck on the boot screen with the apple logo and progress bar completed.

I did run the disk utility tool and found no issues with the hard disks. I also notice that holding down the shift key to enter the safe mode does nothing to it; still same screen.

Other key combinations are failing like resetting nvram.

I got work to complete and this is costing me too much time.

Thanks and kind regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue. Tried everything, even reinstalling the OS again (not deleting data) and it didn't help. I solved it by installing the os on an external HD through the recovery of mac (cmd+r on startup), booting my mac from that external HD, retrieving my data (with Migration Assistant), then deleting my internal HD, reinstalling the OS there, and migrating again from the external HD to the internal HD. Took me endless hours because the drives aren't SSD, but I finally managed to boot to my mac without being stuck after the login with almost no data loss. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to format the Mac and did a clean install. This solved it.